# How to diagnose an occupancy sensor that always detects motion?

Tags: electrical, switch

I've had a Lutron Maestro MS-OPS2 installed in a closet for 3 years and it has worked flawlessly. Recently it started turning on and staying on. To my knowledge, nothing has changed. I can manually turn the switch off but after about 30 seconds it turns back on again. I have experimented with the different modes in the switch's manual (vacancy mode vs. occupancy mode), different sensitivity settings, etc. and nothing changes. The switch acts like it sees something.

FWIW, the switch is driving an LED strip that draws about 20W.

My question is: how can I tell if the switch has simply gone bad or if something else in my house has changed? I've had no electrical work done recently and I know of no new devices on that circuit or even physically nearby.

Comment: Find the mouse?

Comment: @SolarMike Lol. I wondered if someone would say that. :-) It's a linen closet, not a walk-in, and I've watched during the 30 seconds it stays off. No mouse activity!

Comment: Do you have a webcam or some other sort of small video camera you can use to monitor what's happening in there?

Comment: I don't have any webcams. Thing is, it's a tiny closet. I used to be able to open it up, make the light go on, then step back and see things time out and switch turns off. Now I do the same and it stays on. Try to manually turn it off and it comes back on. Essentially behaving like something is moving. But while the closet is open, I see no movement. It's a tiny space.

Comment: Could be RFI/EMI, a common issue for PIR sensors. I would suspect new wireless devices. You can prevent that issue with ferrite beads around the input and output wiring; one fat core around each 3-wire bundle. It's also possible the switch has failed from a power surge or back spikes from the led driver, which often aren't designed to be repeatedly powered on/off (poor intake rush current handling, no PFC). I would try a new switch/sensor and see if that helps, otherwise track down some ferrite beads/cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the answer is/was: defective switch. Ordered a new one for $18 from Amazon, swapped it in 5 months ago and it's been working as it used to.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to let everyone know.

Answer (score 5):

### My bet: you have turned *off* Off-While-Occupied

Lutron occupancy sensors have what's called an Off While Occupied mode, as described in [Lutron's advanced programming guide](https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/048461.pdf).  With this mode *enabled*, turning the lights off manually with the tapswitch while you are in the controlled space causes the sensor to keep them off as long as it detects occupancy.  However, if you *disable* this mode, turning the lights off manually with the tapswitch while you are in the controlled space turns the lights off for 30 seconds, but if you are still there once that 30 seconds is up, the occupancy sensor *turns the lights back on* for you.

So, following the instructions in the advanced programming guide to re-enable the Off-While-Occupied mode should fix your issue.

Comment: It's a good tip but I've already experimented with this and no improvement. Thing is, the major clue for me is that it's been working as desired for 3 years and then something suddenly changed. No one else would change the programming and I've checked that the settings are where they have always been. That's why I'm wondering about defective switch or some other electrical change on the circuit.

Comment: @DaveBurns -- at that point, I'd be calling Lutron's tech support up on Monday

Comment: A static cap could have reset the programming.

Comment: A new one is $18 from Amazon. I ordered one and will simply replace. I'll post back when I have results.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Replaced the switch yesterday with the same model. New one works like a charm! I guess the old one either went bad on its own or there was a spike a few weeks ago that it didn't like or ... ?